# Mysql innodb locking: IX should not be granted when X is held, but does

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

According to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-lock-modes.html), IX table locks conflicts with X row locks, and thus cannot be granted when such a lock is held. To quote

> A lock is granted to a requesting transaction if it is compatible with existing locks, but not if it conflicts with existing locks.

The table above shows that IX and X locks conflicts. However, this is not what I experience. Using the mysql command line tool, if I execute the following

```
drop table if exists test; create table test (A int, B int, primary key (A,B), index (A)) TYPE = InnoDB;  insert into test values (1,1); start transaction; delete from test where a=1;
```

and then run the SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS, I get

```
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 0 4604459
Purge done for trx's n:o < 0 4604457 undo n:o < 0 0
History list length 13
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0 4604434, not started, process no 2015, OS thread id 140642069153536
MySQL thread id 55, query id 1689 localhost esben
---TRANSACTION 0 4604256, not started, process no 2015, OS thread id 140642068752128
MySQL thread id 45, query id 1708 localhost root
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
---TRANSACTION 0 4604458, ACTIVE 15 sec, process no 2015, OS thread id 140642068952832
2 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 56, query id 1707 localhost esben
TABLE LOCK table "esben_mosegris-esben-trunk"."test" trx id 0 4604458 lock mode IX
RECORD LOCKS space id 7800 page no 3 n bits 72 index "PRIMARY" of table "esben_mosegris-esben-trunk"."test" trx id 0 4604458 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;; 1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;; 2: len 6; hex 00000046422a; asc    FB*;; 3: len 7; hex 00000000392350; asc     9#P;;
```

Note that the transaction 4604459 holds an X lock on one of the rows in the table, and thus it should not be possible for another transaction to take an IX lock on the "test" table. However, executing

```
start transaction; delete from test where a=2;
```

in another mysql command line client goes straight through, giving the following output

```
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 0 4604460
Purge done for trx's n:o < 0 4604457 undo n:o < 0 0
History list length 13
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0 4604256, not started, process no 2015, OS thread id 140642068752128
MySQL thread id 45, query id 1712 localhost root
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
---TRANSACTION 0 4604459, ACTIVE 18 sec, process no 2015, OS thread id 140642069153536
2 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 55, query id 1710 localhost esben
TABLE LOCK table "esben_mosegris-esben-trunk"."test" trx id 0 4604459 lock mode IX
RECORD LOCKS space id 7800 page no 3 n bits 72 index "PRIMARY" of table "esben_mosegris-esben-trunk"."test" trx id 0 4604459 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

---TRANSACTION 0 4604458, ACTIVE 55 sec, process no 2015, OS thread id 140642068952832
2 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 56, query id 1707 localhost esben
TABLE LOCK table "esben_mosegris-esben-trunk"."test" trx id 0 4604458 lock mode IX
RECORD LOCKS space id 7800 page no 3 n bits 72 index "PRIMARY" of table "esben_mosegris-esben-trunk"."test" trx id 0 4604458 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;; 1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;; 2: len 6; hex 00000046422a; asc    FB*;; 3: len 7; hex 00000000392350; asc     9#P;;
```

What am I missing? My problem with this is that because this bit goes through, I get a deadlock a bit further on since both transaction now holds an IX lock. Or possibly because both tries to grab the same range lock. I could get around this, but I hate however code that specifically addresses mysql oddities, in particular when I cannot explain it.

On a 2nd note, is there somewhere what all those fields in "Record lock" are explained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a ticket http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63665 for this. The reason is that locks only conflicts on the same granularity, so that ROW locks never conflicts with TABLE locks in the table above. In the ticket, I have suggested several improvements to the manual to make this clearer.